# how to use coord_carteisan and coord_flip together in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some weird behavior from ggplot. Here's a MWE:

```
the_data <- data.frame(
   myx <- 1:10,
  lower <- rnorm(10,-5,1),
  mean <- rnorm(10,0,.5),
  upper <- rnorm(10,5,1))
the_data2 <- data.frame(
  myx <- 1:10,
  lower <- rnorm(10,-5,1),
  mean <- rnorm(10,0,.5),
  upper <- rnorm(10,5,1))
```

Now, I want to construct a plot where the end product will have a point for the mean, and a line drawn from lower to uppper. But I want these lines to be horizontal. I also want to "zoom in" on the graph so that only values from -1 to 1 are shown. I need to use `coord_cartesian` because if I use `ylim` it drops the data points that are outside the graph, which messes up the lines. But when I run:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x=myx, y=mean, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), data=the_data) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x=myx, y=mean, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), data=the_data2) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1, 1)) +
  coord_flip()
```

it doesn't apply the "zooming" and switching the two arguments:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x=myx, y=mean, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), data=the_data) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x=myx, y=mean, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), data=the_data2) +
  coord_flip() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1, 1))
```

applys the zooming but not the flipping. What's going on here?

Comment: you forgot a `+` behind `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1, 1))`...

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Still have that problem, though...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`coord_flip` is a wrapper around `coord_cartesian`. You do two calls to `coord_cartesian` with the second overwriting the first. You can do this:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x=myx, y=mean, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), data=the_data) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(x=myx, y=mean, ymin=lower, ymax=upper), data=the_data2) +
  coord_flip(ylim = c(-1, 1))
```

Comment: This makes sense. I figured it was something along these lines, just couldn't figure it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't make sense to have multiple coordinate systems for the same plot. You want `coord_flip(ylim = c(-1, 1))`